# [[: Command not found

Tags: bash, rvm

I'm installing RVM on a system where I don't have sudo permissions. It should work fine in theory, but when I added

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

to bash_profile, it isn't doing what it's supposed to and it gives me this error

```
[[: Command not found.
```

Anyone know what might be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[[" .. "]]" is a bash builtin. Is another shell running the script?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your .bash_profile is being executed by a shell other than bash.

Answer (score 2):

Put the following at the top of your script:

`#!/bin/bash`

This will enforce `bash` to be the interpreting shell.  As mentioned in other answers, `[[ ]]` is a bashism and not POSIX syntax.

Answer (score 1):

RVM is not (yet) compatible with csh, only bash and zsh >= 4.3.5 are supported.

(see http://rvm.io/rvm/prerequisites/)

Comment: `[[ ]]` is bash syntax, not csh, so I'm not sure what your answer is trying to say.